# Getting 'Consent Required' error despite successful permission grant using Oauth URL

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the example from https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client (docusign python SDK). Despite granting access by logging in using the URL given by oauth_login_url below, the subsequent "api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow" call always results in 'consent_required' error. The corresponding integrator key is set up with right redirect URI and key pair (of which I use the private key as private_key_filename below). Note that the account is not associated to any Organization yet. I am not yet there. But I would expect this basic flow to work as is. Any idea what could be causing this error?

```
oauth_login_url = api_client.get_jwt_uri(integrator_key, redirect_uri, oauth_base_url)

print(oauth_login_url)

  https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&client_id=<integrator_key>&scope=signature%2Bimpersonation&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.docusign.com%2Fapi

integrator_key = "<My INTEGRATOR_KEY1 from Docusign>"
redirect_uri = "https://www.docusign.com/api" <== same as in the Integrator Key
oauth_base_url = "account-d.docusign.com"
private_key_filename = "/Users/myname/Desktop/private.key"
user_id = "46933ecb-9aec-4fe3-8efe-7d5777ac9b54"   <== Silly me, anonymized:) but to indicate I am not using email

api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(private_key_filename, oauth_base_url, integrator_key, user_id, 3600)

  Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/Users/userme/projects/docudocu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docusign_esign/api_client.py", line 118, in configure_jwt_authorization_flow
     post_params=self.sanitize_for_serialization({"assertion": assertion, "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"}))
     File "/Users/userme/projects/docudocu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docusign_esign/api_client.py", line 418, in request body=body)
     File "/Users/userme/projects/docudocu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docusign_esign/rest.py", line 244, in POST body=body)
     File "/Users/userme/projects/docudocu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docusign_esign/rest.py", line 200, in request
     raise ApiException(http_resp=r)

     docusign_esign.rest.ApiException: (400)
     Reason: Bad Request
     HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'X-DocuSign-Node': 'CH1DFE2', 'Content-Length': '28', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Expires': '-1', 'Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only': "script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self';style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self';img-src https://docucdn-a.akamaihd.net/ 'self';font-src 'self';connect-src 'self';object-src 'none';media-src 'none';frame-src 'none';frame-ancestors 'none';report-uri /client-errors/csp", 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': 'b009b0a6-19ad-4e58-844e-76fc5b509cbb', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Date': 'Wed, 29 Nov 2017 22:52:10 GMT', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-AspNetMvc-Version': '5.2'})
     HTTP response body: {"error":"consent_required"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using User Consent then you do not need Organization. Only thing you need to configure in your DocuSign account is, `Create IntegratorKey`, `Create RedirectURI`, `CreateSecretKey (only required if you want to know userId using OAUTH APIs)`, `Create Public/Private RSA Key`.

And your Authorization Code Grant URL to get userConsent should refer to same IntegratorKey, redirectURI which were configured in your DocuSign Account. And same Integrator Key should be used in generating JWT as well. Also oauth_base_path should be account-d.docusign.com for Demo environment. I would recommend to create JWT using [JWT](https://jwt.io/) and test the flow using PostMan. And also use [Epoch Time Converted](https://www.epochconverter.com/) to generate iat and exp claims.

Details for JWT related OAUTH is also explained here, [JWT OAUTH](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html), ignore Admin Consent if you are not using Organization.

Comment: Amit, yes I ensured the integrator key is created properly and the JWT config points to the right integrator key with right redirect URI, private key, etc. From the specific error 'consent-required' I suspect I am doing all those correct things right. But the docusign for some reason thinks the right permissions are granted.

Comment: When you created consent url, what scopes have you added in the url? Also try to create jwt using jwt.io website

Comment: Please see the print output in my question. The URL was made with scope=signature%2Bimpersonation by the api_client.get_jwt_uri() . I did not explicitly opt for any particular scope. Yes, I will try the jwt.io. However, I am yet to figure out where to plugin such JWT I get from there in the python code I am trying (which is this sample https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client#usage). Note that the call api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow() is supposed to configure the api_client with the JWT underneath. I hope to figure a way to manually shove in the JWT from jwt.io.

Comment: Upon close inspection of the URL encoding, it turns out, the URI generated by the get_jwt_uri() function of the api_client.py uses "+" as delimiter (scope=signature+impersonation) for the list of permissions in scope parameter whereas " " (space) is expected to be the delimiter (scope=signature impersonation) by docusign oauth. (continued in next comment due to size limit..)

Comment: That causes the Grant URI to prompt the user to only the first 'signature' permission to grant (i.e. "create and send envelopes...) and without second 'impersonation' permission (i.e. "This application will be permitted to request access to your account without you being present"). Correcting that delimiter gave me the right URI in print(oauth_login_url) call. ( Created this pull request https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client/pull/6 ). JWT AUTH doc link in this reply gave clues as to the delimiter type and the Grant UI user response. So accepting this as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're not showing the parameters that you're using for creating the JWT Token. That'd be helpful for debugging.  (You can edit your question to add the additional info.)

In the meantime, check that you're supplying the guid version of the user's id, not their email, in the JWT token.

Also, check out my [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-using-the-oauth-jwt-flow/) for additional info.

Comment: larry-k , I edited to include the parameters I use for the jwt config call. Yes, I had seen your blog earlier before posting my question. That was helpful to understand further. However, I am puzzled why the configure_jwt_authorization_flow call would fail with 'consent required' despite explicitly granting access at the Grant URL including impersonation.